# Error when deserializing a object with an array from mongodb in rust

Tags: mongodb, rust

When i try to find a document inside a mongodb database, one of the parts of the document contains an array.
when the array is deserialized, it errors with the error
the object that i am deserializing contains a string(an id) and an array of an object.
the object contains two strings and i have created a struct for it in rust.

```
message invalid type: map, expected a string
```

the code that i use to get the document

```
 let index = notes
    .find_one(bson::doc! {"owner": auth::get_user(&req).await?.id}, None)
    .await?
    .unwrap();
  Ok(Body::from_json(&index)?.into())
```

mongodb collection example document
[input of the mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDe3H.png)

i have tried deserializing different types and it has not worked

Comment: If you provide the iput we have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: provided the input

Comment: Sorry to nag again but you should always include textual content as text in your question. This makes it serachable and accessible to people using assistive technologies such as screenreaders.

Comment: What does the `Body` type look like? How is it defined?

Comment: its from the webserver im using https://docs.rs/tide/latest/tide/struct.Body.html